# How to force a different filetype to download instead of opening in the browser?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, browser, download

I would like to make my Wordpress website download a file type (say a *rar* file) instead opening it in the browser directly. 
For some reason the files get downloaded in chrome but not in Firefox. Instead it opens up in the browser itself. Its just not me, it opens the file in the browser for all the users that are trying to download it.
These are the solutions that i have already tried but dint work with me :

- Tried editing and adding the following code in the .htaccess file :
  `<FilesMatch "\.(?i:rar)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </FilesMatch>`
- I also tried adding in `AddType application/octet-stream .rar` in .htaccess

Changing the attribute of  html tag to `<a href ="link" download> LINK </a>` works perfectly fine but i want i want automate this process so that i dont have to keep adding the download attr in each and every post.

Answer (score 0):

Set Contntent Type application/octet-stream in response Type